# How do I use a secret variable in a vsts release task?

Tags: azure-devops

I've got a release definition in vsts that needs access to a password I've defined as a secret variable in a variable group. I've linked that group to this release definition but when I run the task the parameter ends up blank. Is there anything special I need to do to get the value of a secret variable?

Definition of the powershell task that uses the password

[image: Task definition]

Linked variable group

[image: Variable definition]

Error output:

```
2017-08-09T14:01:17.9262375Z ##[command].            'C:\agent_work\r1\a\$(AGENT.BUILDDIRECTORY)\RCV\deploys\common\Get-FromArtifactory.ps1' -repoUsername developer -repoPassword  -repoPath libs-snapshot-local
2017-08-09T14:01:18.8168538Z ##[error]C:\agent_work\r1\a\$(AGENT.BUILDDIRECTORY)\RCV\deploys\common\Get-FromArtifactory.ps1 : Missing an argument for parameter 'repoPassword'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.
```

Edited to add more info as requested.

This is the start of my Get-FromArtifactory.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]
    $repoUsername,

    [Parameter()]
    [String]
    $repoPassword,

    # Other params
)
#setup credentials object for arty access
$secPassword = $repoPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($repoUsername, $secPassword)
```

Edit 15/08/2017 - I've updated it to use quotes as suggested by @Marina-MSFT but it's still just passing in blank.

Amended script to print out part of password:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]
    $repoUsername,

    [Parameter()]
    [String]
    $repoPassword,

#other params
)
write-host "pword $repoPassword"
write-host "1st char: $($repoPassword[0])"
```

[image]

```
2017-08-15T09:23:00.8606081Z ##[command]. 'C:\agent_work\r1\a\RCV\deploys\common\Get-FromArtifactory.ps1' -repoUsername developer -repoPassword "" -repoPath libs-snapshot-local -artifactName ipo-deposit-accounts_2.11 -artifactPath uk/gov/ipo -artifactVersion 0.1-SNAPSHOT -downloadDir C:\agent_work\r1\a
2017-08-15T09:23:02.3606174Z pword     
2017-08-15T09:23:02.3606174Z 1st char:
```

Same with single quotes
[image]

```
2017-08-15T09:22:10.6573655Z ##[command]. 'C:\agent_work\r1\a\RCV\deploys\common\Get-FromArtifactory.ps1' -repoUsername developer -repoPassword '' -repoPath libs-snapshot-local -artifactName ipo-deposit-accounts_2.11 -artifactPath uk/gov/ipo -artifactVersion 0.1-SNAPSHOT -downloadDir C:\agent_work\r1\a
2017-08-15T09:22:11.2198723Z pword 
2017-08-15T09:22:11.3761178Z 1st char:
```

Comment: Secret variables in variable groups can work well with release tasks. Can you show the `Get-FromArtifactory.ps1` script that how you used the `repoPassword` variable. And also please check if you name a same variable `repo1.password` in your release definition?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT I've added the script details above. Not sure what you mean by a variable repo1.password in the release definition - it's in the variable group, is that not enough?

Comment: And what's the result if you use a single quotes for `$(repo1.password)` as `-repoPassword '$(repo1.password)'`?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT I can't change the path to the script as it's not inside the linked artifact. And using single quotes round the variable in the parameters didn't make any difference.

Comment: You can directly use `$(repo1.password)` by adding quotes (such as `-repoPassword '$(repo1.password)'` or `-repoPassword "$(repo1.password)"`. But handling (`$repoPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force`) the security variable is not allowed.

Comment: OK, so how can I get that repo1.password value into a PSCredential?

Comment: Actually it's still just passing in a blank value. I changed my script to write out the password and it's completely blank. so I think the issue is still to do with it not being available to the script - see latest edit to post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got it working now, there were 2 things going on.

1. Having . in the name of a secret variable in a variable group
   doesn't work. I recreated this issue in a separate release
   definition/variable group.
2. Even after I removed the . in my var
   names I still had to recreate the variable group for it to work.

Bug for issue with . in variable name raised here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/94475/secret-variable-in-variable-not-group-not-availabl.html

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and it is a bug.